# How do I check NSLog output?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nslog

I would like to check if `NSLog()` for some string has actually printed out something.

Is there a way I can check the length of the output of an `NSLog` statement or create a string from it? It's for a proof of concept, not a practical solution, so best practice concerns can be set aside.

Comment: Are you trying to capture `NSLog` statements coming from code that you don't control, or is this something where you could replace the `NSLog` statement with something else?

Comment: I'm trying to capture statements.

Comment: Well , I'm not sure how everything should be done , but I'm thinking a starting point could be checking the `stdout` file. I think NSLog is writing in it , just like printf does. What I don't know is if and when the `stdout` flushes itself.

Comment: `NSLog` actually writes to `stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the length:

```
NSLog(@"%i",[string length]);

int len = [myString length];
if(len == 0){
   NSLog(@"String is empty");
}
else{
  NSLog(@"String is : %@", myString);
}
```

---

If you want to check whether the string is null or not then try:

```
if ((NSNull *)string != [NSNull null]){

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I know that I am passing data to an NSLog and I know it isn't null. I want to try and retrieve it back from the log as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to redirect your `NSLog()` output to a file. Take a look at "[Redirect NSLog to stdout?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg01161.html)".

This will only affect `NSLog()` calls from your application.

```
int fd = creat ("/Users/parag/Desktop/my_log", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP |
S_IROTH);
close (STDERR_FILENO);
dup (fd);
close (fd);
NSLog(@"this will be written to my_log"); 
// Now you can retrieve it back from the my_log as a proof of concept
```